# OpenCV FREAK returns too many outliers

Tags: c++, opencv, freak

I am trying the quite new descriptor FREAK from the latest version of OpenCV following the **freak_demo.cpp** [example](https://github.com/kikohs/freak/blob/master/demo/freak_demo.cpp). Instead of using SURF I use FAST. My basic code is something like this:

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypointsA, keypointsB;
Mat descriptorsA, descriptorsB;
std::vector<DMatch> matches;

FREAK extractor;
BruteForceMatcher<Hamming> matcher;

FAST(imgA,keypointsA,100);
FAST(imgB,keypointsB,20);

extractor.compute( imgA, keypointsA, descriptorsA );
extractor.compute( imgB, keypointsB, descriptorsB );

matcher.match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB, matches);
```

- The algorithm finds a lot of matches, but there are a lot of outliers. Am I doing things right? Is there a way for tuning the algorithm?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When doing **matching** there are always some refinement steps for getting rid out of outliers.

What I usually do is discarding matches that have a **distance over a threshold**, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
{
    if(matches[i].distance > 200)
    {
        matches.erase(matches.begin()+i-1);
    }
}
```

Then, I use **RANSAC** to see which matches fit the homography model. OpenCV has a function for this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
    {            
        trainMatches.push_back( cv::Point2f(keypointsB[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt.x/500.0f, keypointsB[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt.y/500.0f) );
        queryMatches.push_back( cv::Point2f(keypointsA[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt.x/500.0f, keypointsA[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt.y/500.0f) );
    }

Mat h = cv::findHomography(trainMatches,queryMatches,CV_RANSAC,0.005, status);
```

And I just draw the inliers:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < queryMatches.size(); i++) 
{
    if(status.at<char>(i) != 0) 
    {
        inliers.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

Mat imgMatch;
drawMatches(imgA, keypointsA, imgB, keypointsB, inliers, imgMatch);
```

Just try different thresholds and distances until you get the desired resutls.

Comment: I was curious about your _"Discarding matches that have a distance over a threshold"_ example, but when I tried to include it in my code, I get the error of _"vector iterator + offset out of range"_ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also train the descriptor by giving your own selected pairs. And tune the parameters in the constructor.

```
explicit FREAK( bool orientationNormalized = true
       , bool scaleNormalized = true
       , float patternScale = 22.0f
       , int nbOctave = 4
       , const vector<int>& selectedPairs = vector<int>()
     );
```

BTW, a more efficient version of FREAK is on the way :-)

Comment: Efficient by which parameter or parameters? I need robust FREAK, not fast. I also need robust feature detector like MU-SURF.